# Why do we have multi-target linear regression model? Is it solely because of the overwhelming number of target variables?

Tags: linear-regression

As the title stated: Why do we have multi-target linear regression model (a linear regression model that predicts several targets at once with a unique set of parameters)? Is it solely because of the overwhelming number of target variables? I mean, if the target variables are small, say 2 to maybe 5, why don't we use 2 to 5 different linear regression models? Is that "much more accurate" since we have different sets of parameters for different target variables? This is a noob question. Hope you help me clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: Just some ideas. What if you are predicting position in space given measurements of the sensors? It would make sense to predict all three coordinates at the same time. More generally, predicting targets together may allow you to enforce specific constraints, e.g. the predicted variables must add up to zero. Finally, you may have reasons to believe that predicted values are correlated in real life, e.g. weight and height, predicting them together may allow to extract that correlation in a more natural form.